# How to tell angular the type of values when using orderBy?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make the columns sortable in a table using 'orderBy' filter. my code is like this:

```
JS: retrieving data using $http.get in the controller
sample Json:

  $scope.items = [{id:111, name:'AAA', value:120.5},
   {id:222, name:'BBB', value:215.2},
   {id:333, name:'CCC', value:412.32},
   {id:444, name:'DDD', value:852.25},
   {id:555, name:'EEE', value:742.2]

    $scope.sortColumn = "name";
    $scope.reverseSort = false;

    $scope.sortData = function(column){
        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
        $scope.sortColumn = column;
    };

    $scope.getSortClass = function(column){
        if($scope.sortColumn == column){
            return $scope.reverseSort ? 'headerSortDown' : 'headerSortUp';
        }
        return 'tableHeader';
    };

html:

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td ng-click="sortData('id')" ng-class="getSortClass('id')">id</td>
    <td ng-click="sortData('name')" ng-class="getSortClass('name')">name</td>
    <td ng-click="sortData('value')" ng-class="getSortClass('value')">value</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort">
    <td>{{item.id | number}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.value | number}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

the problem is angular takes my values as String for sorting purposes, however the 'id' and 'value' column types are 'number' and when I use 'typeof()' function in the browser console, it returns 'number'. I tried to use 'parseFloat' for values in those two columns and then it is being sorted properly. 
Why should I parse the values? I don't want to make extra loops in my js code to do those conversions. Does anybody know any better solution for this issue?

Comment: could you give us some of the code you wrote please ? There could be a lot of answers to that, depending on what you exactly wrote.

Comment: So you're saying `orderBy: 'id'` doesn't work?

Comment: I updated my original question with my code sample.

Comment: @ChrisW. the orderBy: 'id' working properly but I want the sorting functionality for all columns so I need to not just 'id' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected. orderBy is sorting based on the type of the column. 
Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/p68c3qdq/) I created using your code. It seems to work as expected. I have changed the values in $scope.items to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you're going to link to an offsite live example, at least also post your code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was I was passing the wrong field name to the sortData() function in the header.